# Is it possible Filter events with wildcards based on recorded indexed parameters

Tags: events, filters

Let's say I have a contract that fire an `event PersonCreated(uint personId, bytes32 indexed name)` every time a person is created.

To query for all the past events with name equal to Jason, we can use:

```
contract.getPastEvents('PersonCreated', {
    filter: {
        "name": [web3.utils.toHex("Jason") ]
    },
    fromBlock: 0,
    toBlock: 'latest'
}).then((events)=> {
    console.log("Events: ", events)
})
```

**[Q]** Is it possible to create filter to query all event with name start with "J" instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `func filterLogs` in https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/7f74bdf8dded0e1ac3c01e043c2ed89d78f308cf/eth/filters/filter.go there is only a check for empty filter and equality (`==`), so the answer to your question is: no it's not possible (nevertheless, it would be cool to have that feature).

```
...
for i, topics := range topics {
    match := len(topics) == 0 // empty rule set == wildcard
    for _, topic := range topics {
        if log.Topics[i] == topic {
            match = true
            break
        }
    }
    ...
}
...
```

If you want to filter by the starting letter, you'll have to define an additional parameter to you event. E.g.:

```
event PersonCreated(uint personId, bytes1 indexed firstLetter, bytes32 indexed name)
```